# Trying to filter out non-numeric values with regex in php

Tags: php, regex

Thank you for taking time to read my question. I'm trying to filter out non-numeric values from a variable in php. This is what I've tried:

```
$output="76gg7hg67ku6";
preg_replace('/\d/', $output, $level)
echo $level;
```

Preg replace should set $level to 767676, but when I echo level it has nothing in it. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$level = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $output);` maybe?

Comment: please see the preg_replace doc.

Comment: You don't show us $level, but you would be replacing instances of \d in $level with $output. 

From the docs: preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\D` to replace the non digits

```
$re = "/\\D/"; 
$str = "76gg7hg67ku6"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Just fyi:

```
\D match any character that's not a digit [^0-9]
\d match a digit [0-9]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM8bX7/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `preg_replace` fixes others are posting, it's worth mentioning that it might be easier to just use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
$output = "76gg7hg67ku6";
$output = filter_var($output, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/AEPIh

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
$input = "76gg7hg67ku6";
echo preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $input);
```

Output:

```
767676
```

regex:

- **[^\d]** match a single character not present in the list

  - **\d** match a digit [0-9]

For more information about `preg_replace()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

And a quote from there:

> mixed preg_replace ( **mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject** [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )

Comment: `[^\d]` is more simply expressed as `\D`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like this:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","","76gg7hg67ku6");
```